# Migrating old project to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.1.2

Tags: android, gradle

I've got big old project for Android to support. It was developed under old Gradle version (2.2.3). I used to work with the latest Android Studio and now I'm trying to migrate this project to the current Gradle version (3.1.2).

I've read guide from Google on this and applied recomendations from it. I managed to fix all issues excepting two. The first one is

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

I made all replacements in my project and as I understand it's caused by a library from dependencies. OK, let's live with it. But the second issue is

> error: resource android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding is private.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource
>   android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding is private.,
>   sources=[C:\Users\alexanderk.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.1.1.aar\b3fbcbe446f57e45b23f5cfcf67ccbb9\res\values\values.xml:203:5-69],
>   original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}*

Google's guide says about this the following

*To resolve this issue, simply replace android:foregroundInsidePadding with foregroundInsidePadding.*

That's OK, I open the problem file `values.xml`, go to line 203 and... surprise, no foregroundInsidePadding here. Moreover, there is no this word in the whole xml. I tried invalidate Gradle cache but the issue appears again after Gradle recreates cache. And I can't ignore this since this issue stop building.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
appcompat-v7-25.1.1.aar\b3fbcbe446f57e45b23f5cfcf67ccbb9\res\values\values.xml
```

Looks like it complains not about values.xml in your project but about one within the appcompat library. Try to bump support library version

Comment: You're correct, it's not about values in my project. I opened the problem values.xml directly from Gradle cache exactly according to path from error message. And yes, I tried to change version for appcompat library (to the latest one), missed to write about this in the question. This didn't help. And to look over different versions of the library at random doesn't seem to be a good idea... Or maybe I didn't quite understand what you mean by "bump version"?